# WordPress, theme Ajax hook for both logged in and logged out users

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I like to know, if a user is logged in, the following hooks will run two times the ajax_get_info() function, or the wp_ajax_get_info will run only for logged in users, and wp_ajax_nopriv_get_info will run only for users that are not logged in?

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_info', array($this, 'ajax_get_info'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_info', array($this, 'ajax_get_info'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

`wp_ajax_get_info` will run ONLY for logged-in users, while `wp_ajax_nopriv_get_info` will run ONLY for non-logged-in users.

So, the way you did it is correct, and will only ever execute once.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph Silber :)